# objective c: pass UIView parameter to a method

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I have a class called Grid and in that class there is a method called drawGrid with parameter of `UIView` (the grid will be drawn in this view).

```
-(void)drawGrid:(UIView*)view
{
    int i,j;
    int x=27 , y=24;
    for (i=0; i<18; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<18; j++) {
            _viewGrid = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,gridSize,gridSize)];
            _viewGrid.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            [view addSubview:_viewGrid];
            x += 12;
        }
        x = 27;
        y += 12;
    }
}
```

In the **ViewController.m**, I have the following code that creates a view:

```
self.viewA = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, 276, 265)];
    _viewA.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_viewA];
```

and also I created an object of Grid class in **ViewController.m** to call the draw method:

```
Grid *grid;
    [grid drawGrid:_viewA];
```

The problem is that the grid is not drawn. Can someone help me solving this problem?

Comment: you just declaring variable of type Grid, but when you executing -drawGrid an message receiver object is nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate and initialise the Grid object:

```
Grid *grid = [[Grid alloc] init];
[grid drawGrid:_viewA];
```